Can I use hline for dynamic values?
I am developing an indicator on tradingview. My wish is to have (ohcl) calculations for the dynamic values I receive and use the horizon line. For dynamic values, the new.line function is recommended, and I use it, but I cannot write a direct price to the price bar on the right, like hline, which is not nice when drawing graphs. Label option etc. It's not very encouraging. Is there a solution to this? I am sharing my sample code script.
yuksek = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dusuk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
kapanis = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


pp = (yuksek + dusuk + kapanis) / 3
r1 = 2 * pp - dusuk
r2 = pp + yuksek - dusuk
r3 = yuksek + 2 * (pp - dusuk)
s1 = 2 * pp - yuksek
s2 = pp - (yuksek - dusuk)
s3 = dusuk - 2 * (yuksek - pp)


var line_pp = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.black)
var label_pp = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_r1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.green)
var label_r1 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_r2 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.green)
var label_r2 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_r3 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.green)
var label_r3 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_s1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.red)
var label_s1 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_s2 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.red)
var label_s2 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

var line_s3 = line.new(na, na, na, na, width=1, color=color.red)
var label_s3 = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_down, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)


if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(line_pp, bar_index - 0, pp)
    line.set_xy2(line_pp, bar_index + 1, pp)
    line.set_extend(line_pp, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_pp, bar_index + 30, pp)
    label.set_text(label_pp, 'Karar Seviyesi ▪ ' + str.tostring(pp, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_r1, bar_index - 0, r1)
    line.set_xy2(line_r1, bar_index + 1, r1)
    line.set_extend(line_r1, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_r1, bar_index + 30, r1)
    label.set_text(label_r1, 'Direnç ▪ ' + str.tostring(r1, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_r2, bar_index - 0, r2)
    line.set_xy2(line_r2, bar_index + 1, r2)
    line.set_extend(line_r2, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_r2, bar_index + 30, r2)
    label.set_text(label_r2, 'Direnç ▪ ' + str.tostring(r2, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_r3, bar_index - 0, r3)
    line.set_xy2(line_r3, bar_index + 1, r3)
    line.set_extend(line_r3, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_r3, bar_index + 30, r3)
    label.set_text(label_r3, 'Direnç ▪ ' + str.tostring(r3, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_s1, bar_index - 0, s1)
    line.set_xy2(line_s1, bar_index + 1, s1)
    line.set_extend(line_s1, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_s1, bar_index + 30, s1)
    label.set_text(label_s1, 'Destek ' + str.tostring(s1, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_s2, bar_index - 0, s2)
    line.set_xy2(line_s2, bar_index + 1, s2)
    line.set_extend(line_s2, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_s2, bar_index + 30, s2)
    label.set_text(label_s2, 'Destek ' + str.tostring(s2, format.mintick))

    line.set_xy1(line_s3, bar_index - 0, s3)
    line.set_xy2(line_s3, bar_index + 1, s3)
    line.set_extend(line_s3, extend.right)
    label.set_xy(label_s3, bar_index + 30, s3)
    label.set_text(label_s3, 'Destek: ' + str.tostring(s3, format.mintick))

I tried to draw hline it but failed.

You cannot use hline() in local scope and cannot use it with dynamic values.
The usual workaround is to use line and labels. However, you stated that you are looking for a different solution.
One solution could be to plot them with plot() and use show_last=1 so that you won't have history and trackprice=true so that it will be a horizontal dashed line.
Then from your chart settings, you can select Name and value from the Indicators and financials drop-down menu. This way, it would mark the value and the name on the price scale.
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

currentTF = timeframe.period
yuksek = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dusuk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
kapanis = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, currentTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

pp = (yuksek + dusuk + kapanis) / 3
r1 = 2 * pp - dusuk
r2 = pp + yuksek - dusuk
r3 = yuksek + 2 * (pp - dusuk)
s1 = 2 * pp - yuksek
s2 = pp - (yuksek - dusuk)
s3 = dusuk - 2 * (yuksek - pp)

plot(r1, "R1", color.red, show_last=1, trackprice=true)
plot(s1, "S1", color.green, show_last=1, trackprice=true)


Kolay gelsin.

thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I can't get exactly what I want. I use barstate.islast to delete historical points. This time it is deleted at the points included in the price bar to the right. I think my only chance is to use new.line...
